# How to identify the speaker of a voice note

Tags: python, python-3.7, google-speech-api

I want to build a project that allows me identify the speaker. I want my users to say some sentence, record and send to me. I will then identify the words spoken and tie the user to a voice e.g. `00001`. So if they decide to use some of my 'protected' services, they will have to say those words again. If the new voice matches `00001` and words match the previous words, they will be granted access to the services.

I have researched on Google Speech API but I see I can only get the words spoken and not the voice. I am looking at this article - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/speech-recognition-in-python-using-google-speech-api

Please, are there other APIs that offer what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with https://dialogflow.com/ I didn't test it, but in my company is being used to trigger actions based on what a user says.